# .NET 2.0 custom scroll bar control

Tags: .net

I have WinForms application with scroll bar controls, I need to change the appearance of these `scrollbars`.

Is there any way to do it except creating scroll bar control from scratch? I cannot use WPF because targeting .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember the only way to do something like this would be to inherit from the standard control and then override OnPaint() method.

In .NET 2.0 it wasn't possible to do it any other way.

In case you change your mind and decide to go down the custom control path here is a great example from CodeProject > http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I should have know better than to say that there is no other way :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyScrollBar : VScrollBar
{
    public MyScrollBar()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(SystemPens.ControlDark, e.ClipRectangle.Left, e.ClipRectangle.Top, e.ClipRectangle.Width - 1, e.ClipRectangle.Height - 1);
    }
}
```

There *is* a way, however it may be hard to keep the proper positions of scrollbar track and buttons. You can start from here, anyway.